# Table alias is not recognized in subquery Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, alias

I have SELECT statement with LEFT JOIN and joined tables are sub-queries. And Oracle could not recognize alias of the first sub-query in the second one. It works for DB2 but does not work for Oracle.
How I can implement it or rewrite my query?

```
SELECT *                  
 FROM                                                      
 (SELECT     E.C3 AS  COLUMN3        
    , E.C4 AS  COLUMN4        
   FROM TBL_1 D                            
    , TBL_2 E                            
WHERE D.C6  =  E.C6 ) B                                                              
LEFT  JOIN  TABLE   
(SELECT  C.C1                          
 FROM    TBL_3  C                   
 WHERE                                                  
 C.C7            = 'hello'      
 AND B.C3            = C.C8                            
UNION ALL                                                 
 SELECT  C.C1                          
    FROM    TBL_3  C                
    WHERE                                               
    C.C7          = 'world'      
    AND B.C4          =  C.C8                       
    )            A               
ON 1 = 1
```

Oracle error message:
    *ORA-00904: "B"."C3": invalid identifier*

Comment: I don't know about DB2, but this looks like SQL Server's `CROSS/OUTER APPLY` or PostgreSQL/Standard SQL's `JOIN LATERAL`. Check if this helps: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1

Comment: What is the exact ORA- error message that you got?

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify this query to the following, removing the sub-queries:

```
Select      A.Col1, B.Col2
From        tbl_AJoin   A
Left Join   tbl_BJoin   B   On  A.col1 = B.col1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But my query is not so simple. There are just a simplified sample in my question. I suppose that real query could not be simplified in the way which you have suggest. May be you have some other ideas? I tried to rewrite it with WITH clause, and using Oracle (+) JOIN representation, but it doesn't help me

Comment: Perhaps, if the solution to the query you supplied in the question doesn't help you, perhaps you need to update your example query to more accurately reflect your actual query. A bit like asking a mechanic how you can fix a fault in your bicycle when you're really trying to repair your motorbike... why not just ask how to fix your motorbike?!

Comment: Sorry for this inconvenience. I have edited my query

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error.  This:

```
select * from (select col1 from tbl_Ajoin) A
left join table (select col2 from tbl_Bjoin where A.col1 = tbl_Bjoin.col1) B     
ON 1 = 1
```

should be this:

```
select * from (select col1 from tbl_Ajoin) A
left join (select col2 from tbl_Bjoin where A.col1 = tbl_Bjoin.col1) B     
ON 1 = 1
```

or more specifically, this:

```
left join table (select
```

should not have the word `table`.  It should be this:

```
left join (select
```

Comment: Thank you for your mention. But the provided example is correct according to sql rules and works for DB2. I think that removing 'table' doesn't affect to resolving my problem about subquerires

Comment: @WalentynaJuszkiewicz What do you expect the table keyword should achieve?